# I'd go to prison to return to US -- how exactly do you understand that? (context: news article headline)

Tags: comprehension

Source: [Snowden: I'd go to prison to return to US](http://news.yahoo.com/snowden-id-prison-return-us-175045276.html)

Example:

> Snowden: I'd go to prison to return to US

That's the title of that news article by the Associated Press. I'm having a hard time interpreting what exactly that says. To say that he would go to prison to return to the U.S. almost sounds like the only way for him to return to America is first go to prison and then return to the U.S. I am really not following that. Could you spell things out for me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intended meaning might be "I would **even** go to prison in order to return to the US". That is, Snowden is willing to sacrifice his freedom provided that he finally returns to his motherland. He is indicating the extent of his desire to return by saying he is prepared for incarceration.